# Apache Kafka: How to find out consumer group of a topic?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, command, apache-kafka

I am working on Kafka with Spark streaming in Scala. There are multiple topics from which I need to fetch messages. For that, I need to input consumer group of each topic.

I have tried following command:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group group_name
```

For this, I need to mention consumer group and check whether my topic falls under this group. But I don't know the consumer group value for some topics.

So, **is there any command or programmatic way** of finding consumer group for a given topic?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: anybody, please suggest a command or API to get consumer group.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `kafka-consumer-groups --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`; do echo $i; (kafka-consumer-groups --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group $i 2>&1| grep mytopic); done
```

It takes some time, because it checks all the topics, but tells which consumer groups use the topic.

Comment: Having to loop over everything is time consuming but worked for me. I do hope there will be an easier way eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from various topics by specifying the topics. You can simply create a Map of topics.  Refer to the below link

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_consumer_group_example.htm

Comment: I'd gone through the link you suggested. The code requires consumer group and topic as command line arguments. But in my case I have only topic name and I need to know the consumer group of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Command/API provided by kafka to list consumer groups consuming from a specified topic. Instead you can use a tool developed by yahoo to manage kafka clusters : [Yahoo Kafka Manager](https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager). After installing this software and pointing yahoo kafka manager to your kafka cluster, you can view consumer groups consuming from a specified topic.